# Chrome opened from slack and other apps is in the wrong sidebar group

Tags: 18.04, unity

If I open a chrome window from another app - such as slack or when vscode or terminal launches a window the new windows sit under the opening app in the sidebar. This happens even if I open a new Chrome window normally, by clicking on it in the sidebar it also appears under vscode or slack.

Comment: Please mention the version of Ubuntu you're on.

Comment: For Slack you can check [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103461/slack-shows-opened-links-to-browser-as-another-slack-instance-in-task-bar)

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem with Firefox and I found my solution here [Slack shows opened links to browser as another slack instance in task bar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103461/slack-shows-opened-links-to-browser-as-another-slack-instance-in-task-bar?rq=1) but please, attention to use the response from user `bltcrew`