# Open Google Chrome counts as other apps in the sidebar

Tags: google-chrome

I have encountered a curious and strange bug. when I log into Ubuntu and open the Google Chrome app, it counts as another random application on the sidebar. Yesterday it was VS Code and today it is Slack. I searched and found a similar question here: [Chrome opened from slack and other apps is in the wrong sidebar group](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1202609/chrome-opened-from-slack-and-other-apps-is-in-the-wrong-sidebar-group)

But in my case, it is not just the links opened from Slack. Even when I click on the Google Chrome icon it starts as an Slack instance. (or yesterday, a VScode instance) It is annoying, how can this be fixed?

[image]