# Apps are running into another apps like a new instance

Tags: firefox, gnome-shell, zoom-meeting, slack

What I notice is that one App (let say Slack), has a link in a message, when I click on it, it opens Firefox, but in way that this Firefox is linked to Slack. It doesn't even show the dot under Firefox icon, but add one dot at Slack. The problem I notice is that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> loses performance since Slack and Firefox are under Slack, and in the first time firefox opened as a pretty fresh one, without my account and user settings (I had to do all of this twice) so it's as if I have two firefox, one 'free' and one 'bound to'... it happens for all kinds of situations that one app opens another one.... VSCode to firefox / Slack to Zoom / Zoom to firefox...

Is there any way to make apps open in their own place?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the related questions, but aftes I publish it, the forum itself show me someones... I found my solution here [Slack shows opened links to browser as another slack instance in task bar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103461/slack-shows-opened-links-to-browser-as-another-slack-instance-in-task-bar?rq=1) but please, attention to use the response from user `bltcrew`