# Slack opens browser as slack instance if browser isn't already open

Tags: 20.04, firefox, slack

I have the latest Slack version through `snap`.

> installed:          4.9.1            (28) 144MB classic

My issue is similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103461/slack-shows-opened-links-to-browser-as-another-slack-instance-in-task-bar/), but if I have Firefox open already, a new tab is opened correctly. If Firefox is closed, then a new app in Slack is opened.

I followed the other question's answer and checked `about:profiles`, but only have a single profile there:

[image]

I would like to avoid downloading specific version packages, if possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Slack shows opened links to browser as another slack instance in task bar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103461/slack-shows-opened-links-to-browser-as-another-slack-instance-in-task-bar)